# Problem with installing Ubuntu

Tags: server

When I install ubuntu ..
First 
I cannot choose anything in the installer 
Just freeze and after that the tab close 
And say..

THE installer encountered an unrecoverable error..
A Desktop session will now be run so that you may investigate. The problem or try installing again.

I am installing by USB

The version 14.04 
32 Bit

Please help guys I need help

Comment: Does the md5 checksum for the iso used match what is on the site? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VerifyIsoHowto  .... and http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/MD5SUMS

Answer (score 1):

It seems likely that your installation media is corrupted, that's the most common cause of this kind of installation error.

You should MD5 test the .iso image you downloaded. If that doesn't work out, then you'll have to download a new .iso and start over. try this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM for testing the MD5

you can also check the usb or CD for defects